# Object Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script that fetches information from a remote server using SOAP. After figuring out how to use SOAP, I got stuck on the response sent. I am unable to parse the data since it appears that my array is an object array. How would I be able to parse the data correctly?

**Code:**

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'https://192.168.1.10/requests.asmx?WSDL';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$xml_array['StartTime'] = "2014-01-27T00:00:00";
$xml_array['EndTime'] = "2014-09-27T23:59:00";    

$login = 'test';
$password = 'test';

try
{
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $login, 'password' => $password, 'trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
   $response = $client->GetAll($xml_array);
}

catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error!";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
   echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

//echo $response->["Title"];

//var_dump($response);


?>
```

**Response from Server:**

```
[1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (19) { ["ID"]=> int(200) 
["Title"]=> string(13) "Test" ["StartTimeUTC"]=> string(20) "2014-09-24 05:00:00Z"     
["EndTimeUTC"]=> string(20) "2014-09-27 05:00:00Z" ["OwnerId"]=> int(10) 
["UserName"]=> string(13) "testuser" ["FirstName"]=> string(7) "Test" 
["LastName"]=> string(12) "User" ["Email"]=> string(27) 
"test.user@my.lab" ["ServiceType"]=> string(7) "Default" }
```

***Newest Code**

```
$wsdl = 'https://192.168.1.10/requests.asmx?WSDL';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$xml_array['StartTime'] = "2014-01-27T00:00:00";
$xml_array['EndTime'] = "2014-09-27T23:59:00";    

$login = 'test';
$password = 'test';

try
{
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $login, 'password' => $password, 'trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
   $response = $client->GetAll($xml_array);
}

catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error!";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
   echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

function objectToArray($response)
{
if (is_object($response))
    $response = get_object_vars($response);
if (is_array($response))
    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $response1);
else
    return $response;
}

$array = objectToArray($response);

echo $array['0']['Title'];

print_r($array);
```

Server Response from newest code:

```
Array ( [GetAll] => Array ( [Conference] => Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[ConferenceId] => 1 [Title] => Test [StartTimeUTC] => 2014-05-23 11:36:15Z 
[EndTimeUTC] => 2014-05-23 12:06:15Z
[OwnerId] => 2 [UserName] => testuser [FirstName] => Test 
[LastName] => User [Email] => test.user@me.lab 
[ServiceType] => Default )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st solution**

Use this function to convert an `object` to an `array`:

```
/**
 * @param  Obj     The object to convert
 * @return Array   The converted array
 */
function objectToArray($obj)
{
    if (is_object($obj))
        $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
    if (is_array($obj))
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
    else
        return $obj;
}
```

**2nd solution**

For json object you might want to use **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**:

```
json_decode($jsonObj);
```

From the documentation:

> Return Values
>
> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

**3rd solution**

Only if your object properties are public:

```
$array =  (array) $object;
```